# How do I remove Need For Speed World?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I tried Need For Speed World to see if it was a fun game, but it wasn't. So I want to remove it, but there is no built in uninstaller and I can't find it in the list of removable software.

I'm a novice with Windows as I'm used to Mac and Ubuntu.

What can I do to completely remove it?

The problem is that I can only find the game inside the `Games` folder, and there is no separate EA games folder as the official uninstall says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EA provides [instructions for uninstalling Need For Speed World.](http://web.archive.org/web/20130622171418/http://www.needforspeed.com/news/need-speed-world-uninstall-faq)

Since their website has removed the page, the link above now is to the Internet Archive.

They suggest using one of the following options:

- the uninstaller found by navigating to [Start button] -->[Programs] --> [Electronic Arts] --> [NFS World]
- Add/Remove Programs found in the Windows Control Panel. Remove "Need for Speed World"
- [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com)

Comment: In essense - use the uninstaller in the program menu or add/remove software. If hat fails. They recommend revo uninstaller pro

Comment: More like, I was trying to get the gist of his link as a comment, so that if the link goes down... I should have mentioned that too ;p

Comment: I looked again in the uninstaller program and there it was way down the bottom. just thought it would show it's actual size...

Comment: That link is dead. :-/

Comment: @RainerBlome: [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130622171418/http://www.needforspeed.com/news/need-speed-world-uninstall-faq) to the rescue! :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the instructions found on the IA page. Thanks for digging that up, Karan.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) as that can usually find and remove most programs.  Works great on malware too.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer again.  Many installers will detect the application is already installed and give you an option to uninstall the software.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 8, Windows shows NFSW in the list of installed programs, and lets you "uninstall" it. This makes the package vanish from that list, but the files stay.

On my system, the files were located at `C:\ProgramData\Electronic Arts\Need for Speed World`. Just delete that folder. That may take a while, because there are tens of thousands of little files there.